# Getting "None" as output while trying to reverse a list

Tags: python

I am new to Python so please bear me and see my problem and help me to solve my problem.

Here I just tried to **Reverse** a list using **reverse()** method. But I left with confusion after seeing the outputs.

Here are the ways what I tried.

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6]
a.reverse()
print(a)     #print1
print(a.reverse()) #print2
b=a.reverse()
print(b)     #print3
```

**Output for the above code is:**

```
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
None
None
```

Here I don't understand why I am getting **None** as output for **print2** and **print3**

Comment: reverse method reverses the list in-place and it returns None

Comment: This means that the list will be reversed itself. If you want to just get the list backwards add [::-1] to the end

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate your explanation.

Comment: `.reverse` changes the list object by itself, and returns `None`. After you call it, you can use the list. You should not try to use the return value, because the return value will just be `None`. You should call `.reverse` on the list, and then use the list. Like in your first `print`. There is nothing to explain, so we can't answer "why". It was designed that way because the designers of the language want it to work that way.